# SQLite - триггер и rollback транзакции

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, transaction, транзакции

Предположим следующие ситуацию.

БД sqlite
Начата транзакция БД через андрид-программу
Запущен код через эту транзакцию на апдейт таблицы abonent
Есть на этой таблице триггер, который меняет таблицу address
В программе возникла ошибка и транзакция не завершилась (rollback). И следовательно откатились обновления таблицы abonent.

Вопрос - откатится ли в этом случае изменения в таблицу address внесенные через триггер?

Comment: Судя по статье [Механизм атомарного коммита в SQLite](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181584/) в Хабре, да, все должно откатиться.